# Recommended Probability Book

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, references

I'm in a Master's program in Applied Statistics.  I'm taking three courses, and have A's in two of them (Non-Parametric and Survey Sampling), so I'm not (completely) innumerate.  The third, however, is probability theory, and it is destroying me. We are using the Rice book (Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis), which I find to not be particularly helpful -- in particular there is a disconnect between the degree of difficulty of what is covered in the chapters and in the problems.  I'm looking for a book that covers most of the same material at about the same level, but perhaps with more explanations and worked out examples.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

I've looked at the other similar questions, but it seems that they are either looking for higher level books, or pure self-study.

Comment: "A First Course in Probability" by Ross is pretty good.

Comment: You may like to see my post in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162411/intermediate-level-book-for-studying-statistics/162421#162421

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability theory books for self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/probability-theory-books-for-self-study)

Answer (score 1):

I think the book "[Introduction to Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123948118)" by Ross covers the topics you are looking for it has a lot of examples which might be helpful.