# What is a good introductory book in multivariate probability theory?

Tags: probability, references

I want to read my **first book in multivariate probability theory**. It will be nice the book to **have real world examples**.

Comment: This is very broad. Can you tell us about your background?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen , I have a good knowledge about one variable probability theory. Also I studied multivariate probability theory when I was at university and I read two books about this subject, but I want to start it again from the beginning with a nice book with more examples and less calculus.

Comment: Less calculus, then maybe with simulation/programming? Which language? R?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen , I mean with examples, not solutions, without calculus. Examples from physics, social sciences etc. Not only proofs and examples with cards, I 'm not addicted to gambling.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239431/book-recommendations-for-probability, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239139/recommended-probability-book, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70545/looking-for-a-good-and-complete-probability-and-statistics-book, do some of this help?

Comment: Without some more details from you this is probably a duplicate. Can you tell if some of what I linked above suit you? There is a lot of open material to be found by googling, for example http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~winkel/ASim11.pdf

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen , thanks for your answers. I want a book about multivariate probability theory. I think that links are about probability in general.

Comment: That is still very wide! Stochastic processes? Simulation? Give some topics ...