# Recommended textbooks for student majoring in applied statistics

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, references, inference, descriptive-statistics

I am currently a second year science student double majoring in biochemistry and applied statistics. The stats course im doing this semester (Statistical Theory) is focused on joint probability distributions, moments of univariate distributions, moment generating function, distribution of sample statistics and parameter estimation. We have no recommended textbook for this course (instead my college offers their own notes with tutorial exercises at the end). I wrote my first test for this course and it turns out that the tutorial exercises are extremely easy (and few) in comparison. Can anyone recommend textbooks (with practice questions) so i can become more confident with anything they might throw my way??

Thank you

Comment: See also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breferences%5D+applied+statistics

Comment: This as well https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162411/intermediate-level-book-for-studying-statistics/162421#162421